# How is Schrodinger's model of atom consistent with reference to Maxwell's Theory of Electromagnetic Radiation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, acceleration, orbital-motion, atoms, stability

When Rutherford proposed his model of atom, he mentioned that "Nucleus is surrounded by electrons that move around the nucleus with very high speed in circular paths called orbits. James Maxwell contradicted this with his theory of electromagnetic radiation which stated "Charged particles, when accelerated, should emit electromagnetic radiation". In Schrodinger's model of atom, the electrons move around the nucleus within a permissible zone.

The question is that even in the latter case, the electron is moving around the nucleus in undefined paths, which means that the electron is an accelerated, charged particle. How in this case electromagnetic radiation is not given out by it? It is just stating that electrons do not lose energy while moving around the nucleus. What is the actual reason for the electron not losing the energy in form of electromagnetic radiation?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86534/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't electrons crash into the nuclei they "orbit"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20003/)

Comment: To throw in one more link https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68381/